# How to make caps lock key work only for alphabets (in German keyboard on windows)?

Tags: keyboard, capslock, german

When the input keyboard layout is german in Windows 10, and the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> is on, then the whole keyboard behaves like the <kbd>shift</kbd> key is locked. This causes it to type symbols instead of numbers when <kbd>caps lock</kbd> is on.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is annoying for people who are used to English keyboards and for some needs, switch to German keyboard.

One solution I found is:

**On windows, Settings > Time & Language > Language > Under Preferred Language, select German (Germany) > Options > Under Keyboards, add keyboard > select German (IBM) QWERTZ keyboard.**

In German (IBM) QWERTZ keyboard, the behaviour of capslock is same as in an english keyboard.